# Django Application running on Ubuntu VPS: This site can’t be reached

Tags: django, ubuntu, server, firewall, vps

I am running an ubuntu 16.04 cloud VPS server. I've set up a venv and activated it, and installed django.
I run the server with

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I am trying to access this application from a remote computer (not inside the same LAN); I'm trying to make the application visible to the world outside the VPS and VPLAN. When I try to access the site in my home computer broswer like: xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8000 I get the error:

> This site can’t be reached. http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8000/ is unreachable.

Now I've tried a traceroute and it seems to reach the server ok. I also did

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw 8000 allow
sudo iptables -S | grep 8000 (and see the proper entries)
```

In the settings file I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*", "0.0.0.0", "localhost", "xx.xx.xxx.xxx","xxx.temporary.link"]
```

If I wget localhost:8000 I get a response fine. I have tried doing all of the above as root and as another dedicated user but it makes no difference.

I ran through this guide

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

and I still have the same issue.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

Not:

```
sudo ufw 8000 allow
```